# change custom post type permalink structure and remove slug

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, slug

I want change custom post type permalink structure and remove custom post type slug Simultaneous. How can i do that?

> slug= 'recipe-items'

`/recipe-items/%postname%/` to `/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/%post_id%/`